# Pass color attribute from custom view to drawable shape in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view that uses two `<shape>`'s as background in the view xml. Right now I have hardcoded the `<solid color=""/>` of the shape, but I would like to pass the color as an argument from code to the custom view and forward to the shape.

How do I achieve this? I'd like to pass a color reference to both `@+id/rectangle` and `@+id/triangle` from code.

**Shape:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/giddyologyOrange"/>
    <padding
            android:left="0dp"
            android:top="0dp"
            android:right="0dp"
            android:bottom="0dp"
            />
    <size android:height="60dp"
            />
    <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#C95800"
            />
</shape>
```

**View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rectangle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconImageView"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:contentDescription="Icon"
            android:src="@drawable/iconplaceholder"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <View
            android:id="@+id/spaceView"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="10dip"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:maxWidth="150dip"
            android:text="This is a really long text that should wrap"/>
</LinearLayout>

<View
        android:id="@+id/triangle"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle"
        android:rotation="180"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a color filter to colorize the background image.

```
rectangle.getBackground().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC);
```

Since the color comes from my model object this seemed like a pretty easy and maintainable solution.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
LinearLayout myView;

myView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rectangle);

myView.setBackgroundColor(current_color);
```

I have a layout that has an **ImageButton**

```
<ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/color_swatch"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_btn_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_btn_width"
                    android:background="@drawable/checker_tile"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
                    android:src="@drawable/paint" />
```

my **src** is a layer-list drawable--

```
layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FF999999" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <stroke
                android:width="4dp"
                android:color="#FF999999" />
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    </layer-list>
```

the **background** is a layer-list drawable-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="500"
                android:startColor="#17568A"
                android:endColor="#494C4F" />  

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/checkerpattern"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I am able to setBackgroundColor to any color with 50% opacity and see the checkerpattern below

Comment: But I set the background to a drawable (the shape) (android:background="@drawable/rectangle") , so I think I need to manipulate the shape, not the backgroundColor of the view.

Comment: did you try? i am going to edit my answer to show a demonstration i have

Comment: No, I haven't tried. Just felt like it would either be ignored or override the background attribute. Do you mean that the backgroundColor will be passed to the shape referenced in the background attribute?